# Añadir linea de texto en archivo .txt solo si ésta no existe

Tags: python, archivo

Como dice el título, tengo un código que busca URLS en una web, una vez tengo una lista con las URLS creo un archivo, este archivo se crea con las primeras URLS (las 10 que salen en la primera página ) una vez hecho, quiero hacer otra búsqueda, solo añadiendo las nuevas URLS, pero solo consigo sobre escribirlas todas...

Esto no me sirve ya que las nuevas url las enviare a mi chat de telegram con Python también, es decir, no quiero reenviar 10 o 15 urls constantemente, solo quiero que mande mensaje cuando hay urls nuevas, es decir que compare el texto dentro del archivo o lista, si este es diferente al que ya esta dentro que mande un telegram.

Este es el código:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url=input("Escriba la web de la que quiere extraer información: ")


r=requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

list= ''

add='url faltante' #esta es la informacion que hay faltante a lo adquirido por soup

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/s-anzeige/')):
        full=add+link.get('href')+ '\n'
        list += full

print(list)

archivo=open("archivo.txt","w")
archivo.write(list)
```

Por otra parte si veis algún fallo en el código o creéis  que debería deplorarlo de alguna manera, escucho ideas, soy un **novato** en mundo Python y voy perdido.

Comment: debes utilizar append no write! ejemplo `archivo=open("archivo.txt", "a+")`

Comment: si, eso lo haré para no sobrescribir, aun así, la dificultad la encuentro para filtrar los nuevos links de los viejos, para seleccionar los nuevos y mandarlos despues por telegram o lo que vaya a utilizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El modo "w" crea un archivo si no existe y lo abre en modo escritura. Si el archivo ya existe lo trunca previamente, eliminando por tanto el contenido anterior.

La solución sería:

- Abres el archivo en modo `a+`,  el cuál lo abre  en modo escritura, agregando a lo que ya hay (`append`), además de permitir la lectura.
- Como el modo a posiciona el cursor al final por defecto, mueves el cursor al inicio del archivo.
- Lo lees y obtienes todas las líneas, por eficiencia en las búsquedas usa un conjunto (`set`) para almacenarlas. El cursor estará de nuevo al final del archivo.
- Ahora por cada link de la página miras si está en el conjunto de links procedentes del fichero usando el operador de pertenencia `in`, si no lo están lo agregas al mismo.

---

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = input("Escriba la web de la que quiere extraer información: ")
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

links_nuevos = []

add = 'url faltante'

with open("archivo.txt", "a+") as archivo:
    archivo.seek(0)
    file_links = set(archivo)

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^/s-anzeige/')):
        full = f"{add}{link.get('href')}\n"
        if full not in file_links:
            archivo.write(full)
            links_nuevos.append(full)

print(links_nuevos)
```

En cuanto a tu código, solo un comentario. No uses nunca `list` como nombre para una variable, `list` es una [función builtin en Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) (aunque no una palabra reservada) que además actúa como constructor para objetos lista. Al hacer ésto te expones a no poder usar `list` en el script si lo necesitas, generando una excepción en tal caso. Además el código es confuso para otros desarrolladores que lo lean.

La norma se aplica a toda función builtin y si me apuras a los nombres de módulos de la stdlib. Si te vieras forzado a usar un nombre de éstos por legibilidad, raro, pero si se da el caso, sigue las convenciones de estilo y añade un guión bajo al final, `list_` en vez de `list`.

Comment: Que fenómeno que eres! A parte de solucionar mi problema he aprendido un par de cosas nuevas, muchas gracias!!